# Firebase hosting doesn't let me deploy bc firebase-functions is outdated

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, package.json, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

```
functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions.
Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.

=== Deploying to 'zootopia-mysite'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/zootopia/functions
> eslint .

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.

Error: There was an error reading functions/package.json:

 Engines field is required but was not found in functions/package.json.
To fix this, add the following lines to your package.json: 

      "engines": {
        "node": "10"
      }
```

I've also tried to upgrade with npm install --save firebase-functions@latest and it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local project apparently works with both Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions.  The error message is telling you that the Cloud Functions deployment is failing, which doesn't have anything do with Firebase Hosting yet.

If you are trying to follow the advice of the output here, you're going to have to change to the "functions" folder and run the npm commands to upgrade the old modules and make any other changes to package.json.

Comment: Thanks so much! I went into the root directory of my laptop to the users/<myname>/functions and was able to edit the package.json but then after I have deployed, I am taken to this:

Comment: Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary! , so how do I actually view the site I have created

Comment: I don't know, I can't see the contents of your deployment.  Firebase Hosting will simply upload whatever you have in "public".

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out, I was doing firebase init in the users/<myname> directory, but I deleted the firebase.json file in that directory and cd'd into users/<myname>/Desktop/<projectname> directory and ran firebase init and then firebase deploy and I now see it on my hosting URL!